# shorthand for ctor delegate

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following lambda expression:

```
Something((o, i) => new TheNewSwiss(o, i));
```

Is there a shorthand syntax? Something simliar to this but for ctors?

```
Something((o, i) => TheNewSwiss.New(o,i));
Something(TheNewSwiss.New);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no equivalent of method group conversions for constructors. (I can see it being handy, but it doesn't exist.) You just need to use the lambda expression syntax you've got in your first snippet.